# How to add a button in NicEditor

Tags: jquery, nicedit

I'm using NicEditor in a test application, so I had the idea of ​​putting a button to add video from you tube, but does not work until I found the examples even in the example site niceditor, this and that cogido add the button but not appear on the button bar niceditor

```
var nicCodeOptions = {
buttons : {
    'xhtml': { name: 'Edit HTML', type: 'nicCodeButton' },
    'youTube' : {name : 'YouTube', type : 'nicYouTubeButton'}
},
iconFiles: {
    'youTube': '/nicedit/youtube.gif'
}
};

var nicYouTubeButton = nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({
width: '350px',

addPane: function () {
    this.addForm({
        '': { type: 'title', txt: 'YouTube Url' },
        'youTubeUrl': { type: 'text', txt: 'URL', value: 'http://', style: { width: '150px'} },
        'height': { type: 'text', txt: 'Height', value: '560', style: { width: '150px'} },
        'width': { type: 'text', txt: 'Width', value: '315', style: { width: '150px'} }
    });
},

submit: function (e) {
    var code = this.inputs['youTubeUrl'].value;
    var width = this.inputs['height'].value;
    var height = this.inputs['width'].value;

    if (code.indexOf('watch?v=') > 0) {
        code = code.replace('watch?v=','embed/');
    }

    var youTubeCode = '<iframe width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" src="' + code + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

    this.removePane();
    this.ne.nicCommand('insertHTML', youTubeCode);
}
});
nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicYouTubeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Are you adding this plugin script to the nicedit script or an addition to your page?*
I had this problem and this is how I fixed it:

Make use that  sure that `'youTube': '/nicedit/youtube.gif'`  is relevant to your page and not the script and drop the first forward slash 'youTube': `'nicedit/youtube.gif'`It all depends if you are using the plugin on your page or within the Nicedit.js script.

This is how I added code to page (the order you do it is important, I found)

```
<script> Nicedit.js </script>
<script> YOUR PLUGIN CODE (above)</script>
###CONFIG ###
<script>
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
new nicEditor({buttonList : ['youTube','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','fontSize','fontFormat','left','center','right','justify','ol','ul','removeformat','indent','outdent','hr']}).panelInstance('article');
});
</script>
```